# setting shapes in java Scenebuilder

Tags: javafx

I work in java Scenebuilder and I need to change shape of my button,
How can I do that. I can choose properties -> -fx-shape -> then what are the options to choose, I don't have drop down menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no options. You need to come up with a string containing a SVG path on your own.

[JavaFX CSS Reference Guide, `-fx-shape` property of `Region`:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region)

> **Value:** `"<string>"`
>   **Default:** `null`
>   **Comments:** An SVG path string.
>   By specifying a shape here the region takes on that shape instead of a
>   rectangle or rounded rectangle. The syntax of this path string is
>   specified in [3].
>
> [...]
>
> [3] SVG Paths: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html

An example path would e.g. be

```
-fx-shape: "M0,0 H100 V100 H0 Z";
```

For a square (which could be stretched to a rectangle based on the node size size/`scaleShape` property)